# Regular Expression re matching decimals and ints

Tags: python, expression, findall

```
string = '-p 0 0.6724194 0.4034517 -p 0 0 0.4034517 -p 0 0 0.6724194'

arrays = re.findall(r'-?\d+?.\d+|-?\d', string)
```

I've been trying to get a list of just the values after `-p` in the string. The expression i've been using hasn't been working. I'm trying to return something like this:

```
['0, 0.6724194, 0.4034517', '0, 0, 0.4034517', '0, 0, 0.6724194']
```

I'll obviously convert it to floats later, but thanks for any help!

I'm looking for a regular expression fix, thank you for the other options though!

Comment: Will your sting only contain '-p' options, or is your example a substring of something else?

Comment: The commas in your expected output are a bit confusing... Do you need them in your output, or are you trying to get:  `['0 0.6724194 0.4034517', '0 0 0.4034517', '0 0 0.6724194']`?

Comment: I do need them in the output. Each number needs to be seperate.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being dense, but are you looking for a list of three substrings containing comma-separated numbers, or something like: `['0', '0.6724194', '0.4034517', '0', '0', '0.4034517', '0', '0', '0.6724194']`

Comment: Yep! This could include negatives as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> st = '-p 0 0.6724194 0.4034517 -p 0 0 0.4034517 -p 0 0 0.6724194'
>>> [f.strip() for f in st.split('-p') if f]
['0 0.6724194 0.4034517', '0 0 0.4034517', '0 0 0.6724194']
```

Or:

```
>>> [', '.join(f.strip().split()) for f in st.split('-p') if f]
['0, 0.6724194, 0.4034517', '0, 0, 0.4034517', '0, 0, 0.6724194']
```

Or, you just may want to end up with a list of list of floats:

```
>>> [[float(e) for e in f.strip().split()] for f in st.split('-p') if f]
[[0.0, 0.6724194, 0.4034517], [0.0, 0.0, 0.4034517], [0.0, 0.0, 0.6724194]]
```

Or, maybe a dictionary of those:

```
>>> {i:[float(e) for e in f.strip().split()] for i,f in enumerate(st.split('-p')[1:])}
{0: [0.0, 0.6724194, 0.4034517], 1: [0.0, 0.0, 0.4034517], 2: [0.0, 0.0, 0.6724194]}
```

Or, if you really want a regex:

```
>>> re.findall(r'-[a-zA-Z]\s(\d?\.?\d+\s\d?\.?\d+\s\d?\.?\d+)', st)
['0 0.6724194 0.4034517', '0 0 0.4034517', '0 0 0.6724194']
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the period/dot/full stop character matches any character.  You probably want to match the decimal point specifically, so try escaping the period.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
string = '-p 0 0.6724194 0.4034517 -p 0 0 0.4034517 -p 0 0 0.6724194'
for data in re.findall(r'[\s0-9\.]+', string):
    print data.split()
```

results in the following:

```
['0', '0.6724194', '0.4034517']
['0', '0', '0.4034517']
['0', '0', '0.6724194']
```